# $2(u + v)$ and $2(u-v)$ are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be two vectors $u$ and $v$ of $\Bbb R^n$. We assume that $||u|| = ||v||$.

- The vectors $u$ and $v$ are unitary.
- Vectors $2(u + v)$ and $2(u-v)$ are orthogonal.
- The vectors $u$ and $v$ are dependent.
- All the other answers are wrong.
- The vectors $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal.

I have the find the one which is true.

I think that only "$2(u + v)$ and $2(u-v)$ are orthogonal" is true, but it is unclear how I can do that. I know that two vectors $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal if and only if $||x+y||^2 = ||x||^2 + ||y||^2$.

Comment: What is the inner product of $\langle2(u+v),2(u-v)\rangle$?

Answer (score 1):

Two vectors $y$ and $z$ are orthogonal if $y \cdot z$ is 0. Now setting $y=2(u+v)$ and $z=2(u-v)$, it follows that $y \cdot z = 4||u||^2 - 4||v||^2$. If both $||u||$ and $||v||$ are the same then, it follows that $y \cdot z$ is 0, and so $y=2(u+v)$ and $z=2(u-v)$ are orhtogonal.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to see that is using the [Polarization Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), that is, $\langle x,y\rangle=\dfrac14\left(|x+y|^2-|x-y|^2\right)$. Setting $x=2(u+v)$ and $y=2(u-v)$ follows
$$\langle 2(u+v),2(u-v)\rangle=\dfrac14\left(|4u|^2-|4v|^2\right)=4(|u|^2-|v|^2)=0$$